# How to I calculate conditional variance Var(Y2|Y1) in R

Tags: r, covariance

I am sure this must not be difficult but for the life of me, I can't find a function in R to do this.
All help appreciated.

Comment: `https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117142/computing-conditional-variance` may helps

Comment: This too might help [Conditional Variance In Each Regime](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/MSGARCH/versions/0.17.7/topics/ht).

Comment: Thanks for responding - the conditional variance for each regime thing I didn't understand and the first one, I didn't really either. There must be a simple package function to do this surely? I have a question in an assignment and I am short of time and stumped. sigh ...